# Two MVC Projects, sharing Login, not supposed to

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I have an MVC5 project (with other underlying projects), using Web Forms Authentication (SimpleMembership).

Later, I created a second MVC project in the same solution.  I changed the port for IISExpress debugging to be different than that of the original so I can access both sites when I debug.

```
http://localhost:12345/MainAppIndex
http://localhost:54321/SecondaryAppIndex
```

My current login information however, is shared between both projects.  If I log in the first site and open the second, it uses my first login's credentials.

I literally made the second app by copying the first project, tweaking around the .csproj file and solution file, then stripped a bunch of stuff away to start with what I needed. (I also created a new aspnet membership database and pointed the new project to that db, so both apps have their own membership database).

What setting do I have to change for IIS Express to view these as two different logins?

And... will this be an issue in production if a user happens to look at both at the same time (or even swapping back and forth with only one open at once?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a cookie issue.  By changing the `web.config` to set a non-default cookie name (the default being `.ASPXAUTH`, apparently), they are then treated as separate logins.

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name=".ASPXAUTH-PROVIDERS" loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use another database or 2 applications will continue using the same database.

In order to do that, go to Web.Config (at the root) and use other Connection String.

Then go to Models -> IdentityModels.cs and change the name of the Connection string to your new connection string.

Comment: Sorry Dennis, I forgot to put in my question that I did create a separate db for this secondary login, and that's all working fine.  Turned out to be a cookie issue, I'll toss my answer in shortly.